# Angular > test a catchError

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, testing

In Angular, I've created a method for a snackBar. I need to test it but testing is totally new for me.
As you can see in **app.component.ts**, there is a method for the snackBar and when an error appears, the snackBar displays on the screen. The test should verify it displays correctly.
The problem is I don't know how to call the method in **app.component.spec.ts**

**app.component.ts**

```
onClickGetFlows(): void {
  getFlows().pipe(
      tap(flows => this.flowsDestination = flows ? [...flows.destination] : []),
      tap(flows => this.flowsOrigin = flows ? [...flows.origins] : []),
      catchError((error) => {
        this.showSnackbar('The session has expired !', 'Reconnect');
        return of([]);
      })
    ).subscribe();
  }

showSnackbar(content: string, action: string) {
 const snack = this.snackBar.open(content, action);
  snack.onAction().subscribe(() => {
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
 });
}
```

**app.component.spec.ts**

```
it('should call handle function and check snackBar occurrence', () => {
 // Given
 spyOn(showSnackbar('The session has expired !', 'Reconnect').and.callThrough());
 // When
 component.onClickGetWarehouseFlows(showSnackbar());
 // Then
 expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(showSnackbar());
   });
```

Comment: inside the test, is there a spy on the `getFlows` methods?

Comment: There is no test on the getFlows methods. Unit testing is all new to me and there are many things I have to discover and learn